# Adding tableviewcell inside a uitableviewcell and have delete action in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having 3 tableview cells in a TableView, independent of each other i.e. each cell has its own functionality/feature.

Now, in the 3rd cell, I need to have a button that can add rows one below the other and also should be deletable. This is for adding or deleting contact phones for a given user.

**E.g.** There should be a row, with text field in it to enter text. And beside it, there should be a "plus" button so I can add one more row below the existing row. And there is also a trash icon to delete the row.

**Existing 3rd cell**

[image]

**Need to be implemented like -**

[image: sample showing two rows of contact numbers, and delete icon beside the row]

How do I implement this scenario inside an already existing custom tableView cell? I understand that it's easily possible by using custom cells and cell properties like Edit action but how do I implement this within a UITableViewCell?

**Note**: I am at a time situation where I cannot disturb the existing cells and modify things. :-(

Comment: You can use Custom Cell only for third one, for first two cell you can keep using UITableViewCell.

Comment: Arpit: how is it possible within a table view cell?

Comment: Adding a table view cell inside another table view cell using the same table view instance is not possible.

Comment: So you want third cell as UITableViewCell only? You can add subviews like UITextField by code.

Comment: You can edit UITableViewCell like this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson9.html

Comment: @vadian: hmm.. can you suggest an alternate idea please